# Microsoft Office 14.0 access database engine ole db provider in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access-2013

This is my first attempt at writing a Visual Basic app using Visual Studio. I am using an Access 2013 database as the source and everything was going fine until I decided to add some calculated fields to one of the tables. Now VS is telling me that I need the "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider" to read the tables.

I've been searching and searching but can't find anything about version 14.0 of the engine. Am I just missing something simple, or can I not access calculated fields in the DB and have to just pull the data and do the calculations in the app?

I am working on a machine with Win7 64bit, Office 2013 Pro, and Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Thanks!

EDIT: The calculated fields look like this:

"http://travellermap.com/api/jumpmap?sector="+Left([Sector],4)+"&hex="+[Hex]+"&style=print&jump=3"

Where [Sector] and [Hex] are fields in the same database. As soon as I added the fields to the database VS2015 would throw the error. If I tired use the Dataset Wizard it would tell me that there were fields in the database that were missing or could not be read without v14 of the engine.

Then even after I removed the calculated fields it still could not read the data. I have to revert to a backup copy of the database that never had calculated fields in it to get things back to working.

My exact steps were as follows:

- Create database with multiple tables
- Create a view that pulls together data from all the tables that I needed.
- Create dataset in VS that uses that view which I called SystemMaster
- Build app around it using the XAML designer
- Decide that it would be quicker to use a calculated field int he DB than write the VB code to put together a URL that is needed to display an image in the app.
- Close out VS2015 and laucnh Access 2013
- Create the calculated field in the primary table and edit the SQL code for the view to include those fields
- Save and close Access, go back into VS2015
- View the dataset to see if the new fields are there, see that they are not and launch the Wizard only to find out that the Wizard says it can't access anything in that view anymore because fields are either missing or can't be read with the current version of the Access engine (12.0) and that I need version 14.0.
- Search for answer, don't find one. Remove the fields from the tables and try to get back to a working application.
- Realize that even after removing the fields, VS2015 won't read the tables ro views that had them.
- Revert to a version of the database that did not have the calculated views, and everything works again.

While I know that the proper way to do this would be to construct the URLs in the VB code, this was easier and quicker (in theory) to do at this point which is basically a proof-of-concept/prototype.

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem but I could not. Please [edit] your question to give an example of a calculated field expression that causes the issue to manifest itself.

Comment: How did you create the dataset in VS (in step 3)? Your question is missing a lot of details.

Comment: I just followed the basic directions to add a dataset. I don't have it in front of me at the moment, but I selected Database, Dataset, and for the connection I chose "Other" then the OLE DB Connector instead of just selecting "Access" because I had read that for an .accdb file that was what you should do (as per  [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893(v=vs.120).aspx).)